# El margin-top empuja a mi contenedor y no a mi card

Tags: css, html5, margin

Lo que quiero hacer es empujar a mi card con margin-top que se encuentra dentro de mi contenedor, pero cuando le agrego el margin-top a mi card empuja a mi contenedor y no a mi card.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: darkmagenta;
}

.container {
    width: 1400px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin: auto;
}

.card {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: brown;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Porque al colocarle margin-top a mi card empuja a mi contenedor eso no entiendo, en vez de empujar solo a mi card que se encuentra dentro de mi contenedor.

Answer (score 0):

Dale `padding-top` a body; a `.container` y opcionalmente a `.card`. Así logré acomodarlo más abajo del contenedor.

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0; 
}

body {
 background-color: darkmagenta; 
padding-top: 100px; /* Margen superior de body */
}

.container {
 width: 1400px;
height: 800px;

padding-top: 100px; /* Cambias aquí */

 background-color: aqua;
 margin: auto; 
}

 .card {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: brown;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 100px; /* O aquí */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando Bootstrap, con las clase "card-group" puedes solucionar tu problema, esta clase agrega un margin-botton de 0.75rem (12px). Pero solo funciona si tienes varias card.

Ahora si solo quieres agregar un margin o paddig a esa área en especifica yo lo haría de la siguiente forma.

```css
.seccion {
    padding: 40px 0;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.container {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1400px;
}
.card {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: brown;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prueba</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="seccion">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```